# Create table in Hue after many with statements

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am having an issue creating a table in Hue after I do a bunch of temp. table commands. A very high-level example is below..  I am trying to create a table after the many temporary tables are created.

I am basically trying to create a table of the last select statement but I am running into errors both with the create table line and also determining what the last select * table is called..

```
With TABLEA as (Select * from TEST1.FILEA),

TableB as (Select * from tableA)

Select * from tableB
where TableB.Curr = 'TYPEE'

CREATE TABLE TEST 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '|' 
STORED AS RCFile 
as Select * from TableB
```

Comment: please refer to the syntax documentation. Note that these are not temp tables but are `CTE`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query please follow the syntax and examples as below

```
create table as <your_with_clause_select_query>
```

Example:

```
create table test as
with tableA as ( select * from test1.fileA)
select * from tableA;
```

You can also use nested select statements with CTAS.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS
 select * from (
   select
     *
   from
     test1.fileA
 ) b
 row format delimited fields terminated by '|' 
 STORED AS RCFile
```

Comment: I might still be confused but the with clause doesnt seem to work - I have many CTE tables so I have to do the with prior to it... so when I do the below code, I still cannot get it to work..

Comment: With TABLEA as (Select * from Test1.FileA),

TableB as (Select * from tableA)

create table test as
with tableA as (select * from tableA)

Comment: Yes because that is wrong syntax, you need to do `create table test as <your select query>`. You should replace <select query> with your entire query including 'with'

Comment: oh, so I basically just put CREATE TABLE TEST As above the entire thing. Perfect!! Thanks!